# RACSignal for didRangeBeacons:inRegion: not working

Tags: ios, bluetooth, reactive-cocoa, estimote

I'm building an app on iOS 10 using the Estimote SDK. I want to use the range mode to detect nearby beacons. The UUID for the region and beacons is setup correctly as verified in a small sample project.

The app I'm building right now is showing some strange behaviour: After starting the app, **the `beaconManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` method is not called even when right next to the beacon.**

**Disabling / enabling Bluetooth will cause the method to fire immediately. This is also true for pausing the app and resuming it using the debugger.**

What is causing this behaviour? I'm requesting the permission at every launch and wait for the callback to start monitoring (as stated in the documentation). I already tried to setup more startRanging / stopRanging calls (desperate!) but no success.

Any ideas?

```
    @implementation Model {}

    - (instancetype)init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            self.beaconManager = [ESTBeaconManager new];
            self.beaconManager.delegate = self;
            self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]
                    initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc]
                            initWithUUIDString:proximityUUID]
                            identifier:@"Playground"];
            [self.beaconManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

            self.beaconSignal = [self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(beaconManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:) fromProtocol:@protocol(ESTBeaconManagerDelegate)];

            [[self.beaconSignal throttle:1]
                    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
                        NSLog(@"Did range fired");

                    }];
        }

        return self;
    }

    - (void)start {
        [self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    }

    - (void)beaconManager:(id)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
        if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse){
            [self start];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the throttled subscription to *RACSignal* for the `beaconManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:`selector. Removing the `throttle` or the delegate method without a signal works fine.